# Save and close VF page Pop Up on Single Click

Tags: visualforce, oncomplete

I am trying to save and close a VF page on clicking 'Save' command button.Here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closewindow(){
        window.close();
        geopointe.api.closeAction();
    }
</script>

<apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" oncomplete="closewindow();"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

The issue here is oncomplete function is getting executed without saving the record and closing the popup.If I remove the autocomplete function then ,my code is working fine,running validations on page and then saving the record.Does anyone has an idea how can I  perform the save before closing the window?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'd need to use a Boolean property in apex class to know if the transaction was successful. If yes, close popup.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.That solution is not working for me

Comment: Could you share on what have you tried based on that answer, because that works.

Comment: @RahulSharma Maybe it works for that specific situation, but doesn't work here for this situation. In this question, there aren't save errors, as far as the OP knows.

Comment: Ah got it, @DeepikaRaina can you try adding `rerender` attribute and a page message to know if the save was succeeded without any error? Maybe add a working example which we can try?

Comment: Thanks @RahulSharma-The link posted by you actually solved my problem ,I was not rendering my page messages rightly initially.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following way:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="quickSaveJavascript" action="{!quicksave}" oncomplete="window.top.close();"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Save" onclick="quickSaveJavascript();"/>
```

Comment: Not sure how this would help, care to elaborate?